# div alignment - % width

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div inside another one, this is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">  
  <div id="leftHeader"></div>
  <div id="rightHeader"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftHeader {
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  height:120px;
  margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}

#rightHeader {
  width:60%;
  float:left;
  height:120px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the second div appear aligned bottom of the first, I expected them to be aligned horizontally.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the margin that you have set to the left of first div (1px) and to the right of the second div (1px).
So 40% + 1px + 60% + 1px = `100% + 2px`, that's why you see them  not aligned.
 You should remove the margin or use the calc function:

```
width: calc(60% - 1px); and width: calc(40% - 1px);
```

Comment: In case `calc()` is not supported (such as in **IE8**), we can always use negative margin to hack it, like this http://jsfiddle.net/gyQ2W/

Answer (score -1):

The width attached to the two div's IS 100%, which is equal to the entire width of the parent container. However, its the margin added to both of them that makes makes them wider than the parent. Hence, then second div is pulled down so as to fit in within the parent div. Essentially, this is the problem in the `#leftheader` and the `#rightHeader` classes:

```
margin: 0 0 0 1px;

margin: 0 1px 0 0;
```

See your markup and styling here->http://jsfiddle.net/Rk22d/

When the margin is removed, then the two div's fit in within the parent-> http://jsfiddle.net/Rk22d/1/

Hope this helps!!!